# Replace all odd occurrences of a substring using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string `~~40~~ Celsius Temp: 33 Celsius Temp:~~50~~`

I want to replace the odd occurrences of substring '~~' i.e 1st, 3rd.. with another string '**'.

My output should be `**40~~ Celsius Temp: 33 Celsius Temp:**50~~`

How to achieve this with regex in Java?

Comment: This is a very strange use of regex. Strongly consider using something like a loop to do this instead. (Not all tasks can be accomplished using regex.)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will always be an even number of them? Is it okay if it fails, or misses the last one, if they don't come in pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need a rudimentary parser to handle this; regex wasn't designed to count occurrences like this.  The logic of the code below is simple.  Every time we hit a match `~~` we do one of two things.  If it is an odd occurrence, then we append empty string to the replacement, otherwise we reappend the `~~` which we matched.

```
String input = "~~40~~ Celsius Temp: 33 Celsius Temp:~~50~~";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("~~");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input.length());
int i = 0;

while (m.find()) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "**");
    }
    else {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(0));
    }
    ++i;
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());

**40~~ Celsius Temp: 33 Celsius Temp:**50~~
```

### Demo

Comment: You should replace it with `"**"` to match OP's requirement, but there's no real need for *counting* occurrences if only pairs need to be replaced.

Comment: @DavidConrad I disagree with your logic, because who says that we will always have _pairs_ of `~~`.  The actual replacement logic we want here is in fact to iterate through, replacing all odd occurrences, with or without a pair, so...

Comment: Since OP hasn't specified, it is unclear what OP would like to have done with a mismatched pair. It seems just as likely to me that it is considered illegal and ought to be ignored. Until OP clarifies, nothing more can be said.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your problem statement, you no need to search for odd occurrences , from the example it shows, you need to replace ~~(digit) with **(digit) and ignore other formats of ~~ ..

Answer (score 0):

Well some have already suggested similar solution but still:

```
String org = "~~40~~ Celsius Temp: 33 Celsius Temp:~~50~~";
String rep = org.replaceAll("~~(\\d)","**$1");
```

Here, `~~(\d)` will search for `~~` followed by digit and replace with `**`, to preserve the first digit, using `$1`

Answer (score -2):

You can use replacement of a capturing group, iff the `~~` come strictly in pairs.

```
private final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:~~([^~]+~~))");

public static String replaceOddTildes(String value) {
    return pattern.matcher(test).replaceAll("**$1");
}
```

And:

```
String result = replaceOddTildes("~~40~~ Celsius Temp: 33 Celsius Temp:~~50~~"));
```

Note that it will miss the last odd set of tildes if they are not in matching pairs:

```
replaceOddTildes("An ~~un~~ paired ~~example!").equals("An **un~~ paired ~~example!")`
```

If that's how you want an unmatched pair handled, of course, then that's fine.

The pattern in detail:

```
(?:             a non-capturing group, consisting of
    ~~          a pair of tildes, followed by
    (           a capturing group, consisting of
    [^~]+       one or more characters that is not a tilde, followed by
    ~~          a pair of tildes
    )           end of the capturing group
)               end of the non-capturing group
```

The replacement for the match is a pair of asterisks followed by the contents of the capturing group.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain or suggest improvements?